# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden on MVC deploy to FileZilla

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, ftp, publish, filezilla

I have a problem with publishing my mvc website using filezilla. I am getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. I know this is familiar but i can't solve this problem. If you are suggesting that there is no default page, so it must be said that it exists already.

What to do?

below shows a picture of my ftp folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer..Written to hope help someone who see this question..

Try with web matrix ;)

{ Once, with a host company which not fully work with Asp.net and MVC (their most hosts are linux-host) i faced same problem and when i tried to deploy with web-matrix-ftp, it worked }